# Draftjs trying to remove an atomic block

Tags: javascript, reactjs, draftjs

I am trying to remove an atomic block from the draftjs editor with Modifier.removeRange. From what I can tell I am passing in all the right arguments, but the SelectionState for removal never gets removed. 
Here is my code. This also adds in a new atomic block. That part works fine, it's the removal aspect that returns the same contentState that i pass in.

upload_block_selection_state is the SelectionState object for removal. This object is obtained from editorState.getSelection() when it is rendered. It looks like this.

```
upload_block_selection_state = {
 anchorKey: "c1kpk",
 anchorOffset: 0,
 focusKey: "c1kpk",
 focusOffset: 0,
 isBackward: false
}
```

and here is the function that should both remove the upload block and then add a new block. Adding works, removal does nothing.

```
function addAndRemoveMediaBlock(
    entityURL,
    entityType,
    editorState,
    setEditorState,
    upload_block_selection_state
){
    const contentBeforeAtomicBlock      = editorState.getCurrentContent();
    const contentAfterSelectionRemoval  = Modifier.removeRange(
        contentBeforeAtomicBlock,
        upload_block_selection_state,
        'forward'
    );


    const contentStateWithEntity        = contentAfterSelectionRemoval.createEntity(entityType, 'IMMUTABLE', { src: entityURL });
    const entityKey                     = contentStateWithEntity.getLastCreatedEntityKey();
    const editorStateAfterAtomicBlock   = AtomicBlockUtils.insertAtomicBlock(
        editorState,
        entityKey,
        entityKey
    );

    /* 
        below here relevant only to removing the empty block.  
        */    
    const selectionStateBeforeAtomicBlock = editorState.getSelection();
    const anchorKeyBeforeAtomicBlock      = selectionStateBeforeAtomicBlock.getAnchorKey();
    const contentAfterAtomicBlock         = editorStateAfterAtomicBlock.getCurrentContent();
    const blockSelectedBefore             = contentAfterAtomicBlock.getBlockForKey(anchorKeyBeforeAtomicBlock);

    const finalEditorState = (() => {
        if(blockSelectedBefore.getLength() === 0){
            const keyBefore                    = blockSelectedBefore.getKey();
            const newBlockMap                  = contentAfterAtomicBlock.blockMap.delete(keyBefore);
            const contentWithoutEmptyBlock     = contentAfterAtomicBlock.set('blockMap', newBlockMap);
            const editorStateWithoutEmptyBlock = EditorState.push(editorStateAfterAtomicBlock, contentWithoutEmptyBlock, 'remove-block');
            return EditorState.forceSelection(editorStateWithoutEmptyBlock, contentWithoutEmptyBlock.getSelectionAfter());
        }else{
            return editorStateAfterAtomicBlock;
        }
    })();
    setEditorState({
        editorState: finalEditorState,
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.

```
const contentAfterSelectionRemoval  = contentBeforeAtomicBlock.blockMap.delete(blockToRemoveKey);
```

This seems like an anti-pattern within an Immutable state so I ended up approaching the problem from another angle and didn't actually use this working solution.

Comment: Umm... so what was the actually usable solution?

Answer (score 0):

set `focusOffset` to 1 should work if any other parameters are fine.